# Display Facebook tab content for different user languages

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating an app for a client that requires French content to be displayed to French speaking Facebook users. If the user is not French speaking, English content should be displayed. This needs to work in conjunction with the fan-gating.

This is what I have, however it's not working. The fan gate is, but the French content is not displaying (yes, I changed my language in my Facebook settings to French).

To summarize, if the user is French speaking, show fan and non-fan French content, else show default English content.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';

$app_id = "XXX";
$app_secret = "XXX";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
));


$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];
$page_admin = $signed_request["page"]["admin"];
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
$country = $signed_request["user"]["country"];
$locale = $signed_request["user"]["locale"];
$languageFR = $signed_request["user"]["fr_CA"];

if ($like_status) {
    if ($languageFR) {  
        include("fans_french.php");
    }
    else {  
        include("fans_english.php");
    }
}
else {
    if ($languageFR) {  
        include("nonfans_french.php");
    }
    else {  
        include("nonfans_english.php");
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't your line about the language be:

```
$languageFR = ($locale == "fr_CA");
```

Or even better, shouldn't you be looking at ["user"]["languages"], and not the locale?

Comment: I tried a variation of this, but it didn't work. is this what your suggesting? http://pastebin.com/ppmxVayn

Comment: No, not that. If you changed $locale = $signed_request["user"]["languages"]; to $locale = $signed_request["user"]["locale"]; -- that's what I meant.

Comment: Duh! Missed that...it worked! Thanks a ton dude! Here's the updated code for anyone else who needs it! http://pastebin.com/ZftTzDz0

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space)*.

Here is an updated and working script:

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';

$app_id = "XXX";
$app_secret = "XXX";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];
$page_admin = $signed_request["page"]["admin"];
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
$country = $signed_request["user"]["country"];
$locale = $signed_request["user"]["locale"];
$languageFR = ($locale == "fr_CA");

if ($like_status) {
    if ($languageFR) {  
        include("fans_french.php");
    }
    else {  
        include("fans_english.php");
    }
}
else {
    if ($languageFR) {  
        include("nonfans_french.php");
    }
    else {  
        include("nonfans_english.php");
    }
}

?>
```